# How to create database software with custom extension to save and reload later with C# WinForm App

Tags: winforms, serialization, deserialization, extension-methods, software-design

I am working on a project to create a software to keep some data and then export it to pdf files. To do that, i am using sql database and windows winform app. Because of being new to such things, i am not sure to pick correct way.

In the software there are menüstrips and textboxes which enables users to enter some info. End of the data entry, i want to keep the template and save it with custom extension to open and work on it later.

For example, i want to save the program like ozz001.grwt. I want to keep the software with an extension like "grwt".

I use:
SQL Server
Winform .NetFrameWork

I searched in the web and youtube. What i found is to save with XML extension.

Also, i saw serialization. I am not sure is it correct way to follow due to being new.

Comment: Do you want to save (serialize) the contents of a Windows Form as a flat file with *.grwt extension and load it later into a Form?

Comment: Yes, definetely.